# Problemas no uso do método EditText.setError()

Tags: android

Ao tentar utilizar o método `EditText.setError()` a mensagem de erro não aparece. O código abaixo é utilizado por realizar a validação dos campos obrigatórios:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText usuario;
    private EditText senha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);

    }

    private boolean loginValido() {

        EditText campoComFoco = null;

        boolean isValid = true;

        if (usuario.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            campoComFoco = usuario;
            usuario.setError("Usuário obrigatório");
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (senha.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            if (campoComFoco == null) {
                campoComFoco = senha;
            }
            senha.setError("Senha obrigatória");
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (campoComFoco != null) {
            campoComFoco.requestFocus();
        }

        return isValid;
    }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, sem o código que você fez, fica um pouco complicado te falar o que está faltando..Edita sua pergunta e adicione a parte relevante do código.

Comment: Uma pergunta. Você está tentando colocar o erro em um `TextView` ou em um `EditText`?

Comment: Perdão, @sicachester, EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei minha resposta, conforme sua edição

```
 final EditText txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHint);

        txtNome.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    String campoPesquisa = txtNome.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(campoPesquisa))
                    {
                        editText.setError("Informe o usuario");
                        vibrar(200);
                        return false;
                    }
                    }
                }

                return false; 
            }
        });
```

Recomendo o uso do `TextUtils` nesse caso se quer validar se o campo está vazio.

**onEditorAction**: permite definir qual será a ação final do usuário, no exemplo que eu retirei de uma aplicação minha ele dispara quando o usuario clicar em pesquisar e quando clicar em Ok ou done.

Comment: @GeisonSantos, coloca onde você está declarando eles, é um editText mesmo né? Outra pergunta ele está apontando erro? só somente naõ apresenta mensagem?

Comment: @GeisonSantos, alterei minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está correto, você apenas precisa adicionar um "**focus**" para o `EditText` que está tentando atribuir o `setError()`.

Tente algo parecido:

```
if (usuario.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
    campoComFoco = usuario;
    //Adicionando o foco no seu EditText
    usuario.requestFocus();
    usuario.setError("Usuário obrigatório");
    isValid = false;
}
```